# "What songs is Johnny playing" or "What songs are Johnny playing"

Tags: sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural

Which of the two is it? I would assume it would be "What songs are Johnny playing" due to the main noun "songs" being plural, but someone is telling me otherwise, and that since Johnny is the subject of the sentence, therefore the verb must be singular.

Comment: *Is*. A verb agrees with its subject. It's easier to understand if you change it into a declarative sentence(no auxiliary inversions). *"Jonny is playing what songs"*.

Comment: @user178049: Shouldn't that be a full answer?

Comment: Arguably, neither are correct as they imply that he's playing multiple songs at the same time (is would be correct if he were). Will or was are more suitable. If asking mid-set, it could be correct but is still confusing and it might be better to ask what he has played.

Answer (score 3):

It should be *is*.

> What songs **is** Johnny playing

A verb agrees with its subject. It's easier to understand if you change it into a declarative question(no subject-auxiliary inversions).

*"Jonny is playing what songs?"*.